# Hyperlink locations from root directory

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've just made a database in Access which will have hyperlinks to PDF files in a sub directory.

I could simply copy paste the entire directory location, but if I ever change the location of the files (or if we're forced to move them somewhere else) I would have to rename all of them.

It seems a better solution is to tell Access to look in the 'root' directory and search for this specific folder name which will probably never change.

Is this possible?

**For clarification:**

```
Database location: X:/Somewhere/Over/Here.ADB

PDF file location: X:/Somewhere/Over/There/123abc.PDF
```

It would be much better to tell access to search in the "There" folder, which is located in the .ADB "root" directory, to open 123abc.PDF

The alternative is to enter the PDF location values like this:

```
X:/Somewhere/Over/There/123abc.PDF

X:/Somewhere/Over/There/456def.PDF... etc.
```

But if the location of the DB changes to, for example `X:/Somewhere/Else/`, then I need to rename all the locations.

Comment: Where is the Access database in relation to the 'root' directory?

Comment: The access db is X:/somewhere/over/here.adb I want the pdf files to be X:/somewhere/over/there/abc.pdf. But my thought is that "root" should be the location where the db is located, i.e. X:/somewhere/over/. This way I can tell access to look into the "there" folder for "abc.pdf"

Comment: Do you have a split database or a single file database?  If it is split I assume your 'root' folder is located where your backend file is?

Comment: Yes the db is split, currently both files are in the same location (I may not have thought this out well).. The backend file location is what I wish to be the 'root' folder, yes. The frontend of course will be in a different location on every computer.

Comment: I have posted some sample code below let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly for what you are looking for you could use something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim strDBPath as string
    strDBPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\"

    Me.Textbox1.Hyperlink = strDBPath & "PDFs\123abd.pdf"
    Me.Textbox2.Hyperlink = strDBPath & "PDFs\456efg.pdf"

End Sub
```

Though this is based off of your frontend file being in the 'root' folder.

After noticing your comment I will update momentarily with another option to use the backend file.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim strDBPath as string
    strDBPath = Left(Mid(Currentdb.TableDefs("TableName").Connect, 11),Len(Mid(Currentdb.TableDefs("TableName").Connect, 11)) - 10)

    Me.Textbox1.Hyperlink = strDBPath & "PDFs\123abd.pdf"
    Me.Textbox2.Hyperlink = strDBPath & "PDFs\456efg.pdf"

End Sub
```

The 10 is the length of the name of your backend adjust accordingly I can't really think of any way to get that more dynamically.  I feel like something is a little messy with that and there might be a simpler way but that is the ground work for how you can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. My current plan is to create a column that has the address to the PDF. I'm relatively unfamiliar with using "code" in access, would it be easier to take a "root location" from columnA, "PDF Name" from columnB, and then paste the values together into columnC? It seems that is what this is doing to some degree, but again I'm unfamiliar with using this type of code in access

Comment: No time like the present to start down your path in programming :-)